# Porque a matriz não existe fora do escopo do readMatriz()?

Tags: c++, matriz

Estou aprendendo melhor C++ para maratonas e estou passando a usar mais métodos ao invés de fazer tudo na main(), preciso ler uma matriz mas estou com problemas de fazer isso através de um método pois essa matriz não existe depois da chamada da função para ler toda a matriz, ou seja, quando chega na printMatriz() da segmentationFault pois a matriz já não existe mais nesse escopo.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void readMatriz(int **M, int n) {
    M = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        M[i] = new int [n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> M[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void printMatriz(int **M, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << M[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, **M;

    cin >> n;

    readMatriz(M, n);
    printMatriz(M, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Debugando o código percebo que consigo chamar a função printMatriz() quando estou ainda no escopo da readMatriz(), mas fora parece que a matriz não existe mais, o que acho muito estranho pois não estou passando valor e sim referência.

> Se eu pegar essa parte M = new int *[n]; que está na readMatriz() e mover pra main e código funciona perfeitamente e não dá segmentationFault.

Desculpa alguma inconsistência é minha primeira dúvida postada aqui no StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

O problema acontece porque o valor de M é passado por valor. Quando você chama a função `readMatriz` na main, o valor do int** M é passado como uma cópia. É como se um novo int** fosse criado e recebesse o mesmo valor de M. Quando você altera o conteúdo de M, ele é alterado apenas dentro da função. Ao sair da função o valor da variável M original (da main) continua sendo o mesmo que era antes de ter entrado na função.

A maneira mais simples de resolver isso é passar a variável como uma referência. Isso pode ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```
void readMatriz(int **&M, int n) {
```

Note que a única diferença é que temos um `&` a mais após o tipo da variável (int**). Dessa maneira qualquer alteração à variável dentro da função também será refletida fora dela. Assim, na seguinte atribuição

```
M = new int *[n];
```

M terá o endereço da sua matriz mesmo após sair da função.

Não se esqueça que toda memória alocada usando o operador `new` não é liberada automaticamente ao sair de escopo. Então antes de terminar a função main use o operador `delete[]` (com o [] mesmo, pois é um vetor) para liberar a memória alocada dinamicamente. Segue o código completo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void readMatriz(int** &M, int n) {
    M = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        M[i] = new int [n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> M[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void printMatriz(int **M, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << M[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, **M;

    cin >> n;

    readMatriz(M, n);
    printMatriz(M, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      delete[] M[i];
    delete[] M;

    return 0;
}
```